# Density in finite-dimensional subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Is the following true :

If $D$ is a dense subset of a Hilbert space $H$, then $D\cap V$ is dense in any finite dimensional subspace $V$ of $H$ ?

Comment: What if $D\cap V=\varnothing$?

Comment: @Aweygan, or $\{0\}$, anyway. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett In the question's current form, it only states that $D$ is a dense subset, not a dense subspace.

Comment: @Aweygan, ah, true! Sorry! I was thinking about $D$ be a dense subspace, e.g., the domain of an unbounded operator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant $D$ must be a subspace otherwise the answer is clearly No.

In later case if $D$ is subspace still answer is NO in any infinite dimension space.

Let $X$ be infinite dimension space pick the subspace $D$ which is dense in $X$ but it is not entire $X$ (you can always find this subspace! Think about the kernel of a discontinuous linear functional on $X$). Now pick the vector $v \in X \setminus D $ and put $V:= Span \{v\}$ then observe that $D \cap V = \{ 0 \}$ which is not dense in $V$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $H = \mathbb{R}$, $D = \{\pi + q \mid q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $V = \{0\}$. Then, $D \cap V = \emptyset$ which is not dense in $V$.